# Steering wheel shaking when braking

Tags: brakes, steering, steering-wheel

I just got my brakes (front and back) done about 3 months ago, so I know they aren’t bad. But when I go to press on my brakes, my steering wheel shakes pretty bad. Any suggestion as to why that may be? I have an 06 Dodge Dakota.

Answer (score 3):

Has the vehicle done this since the brakes were changed 3 months ago?  If so, I'd return it to them and have them rectify the issue.

Vibration under braking usually indicates a warped brake disc/rotor.  It may be that some other component is causing this such as a failing wheel bearing but it's most likely to be a warped rotor.